# How to reset a CUDA GPU in python

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu

Is there a way to restart CUDA GPU within python ? or release it so that another script can get access to it ?

I sometimes get an error using the GPU in python, and the only solution to get access to the GPU again is to restart my Jupyter notebook.

PS: I am using the GPU for some computation using pytorch.

the particular error I get is:

```
RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
```

I have seen https://towardsdatascience.com/cuda-error-device-side-assert-triggered-c6ae1c8fa4c3 and many others discussing this problem. My main issue is **how to continue using the GPU session without restarting the Jupyter kernel**.

i.e. I would like to catch this error which I do with a try/except and move on since I am training multiple models one after the other so i cannot restart to solve my problem.

**EDIT** restarting the kernel seems to be the accepted naive solution see:

-https://forums.fast.ai/t/how-to-free-up-gpu-memory-in-pytorch-0-2-x/9256/2 
-https://towardsdatascience.com/cuda-error-device-side-assert-triggered-c6ae1c8fa4c3 where she mentions "Working on Kaggle? Here’s why even after following the above steps, you are still struggling"

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the error is?

Comment: @AdarshC I did, however the error itself is not the main issue for me as I also noted

Comment: `torch.cuda.empty_cache()` or `torch.cuda.ipc_collect()` do not work?

Comment: @SzymonMaszke `torch.cuda.empty_cache()` dosen't run, it gives the exact same error. And `torch.cuda.ipc_collect()` runs, but when retrying to train, it gives again the same error

Comment: Don't use Jupyter notebook. Use a simple .py script. It doesn't allow cuda to deallocate resources once the session is over which creates problems.

Comment: @ShreyaPandita I do, this is the reason why I cannot use the restart jupyter notebook solution. But once you get an error at the GPU level, the script catches the error but all following models that are trained are then given the `RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered` error immediately

Comment: Check this out: https://lernapparat.de/debug-device-assert/

Comment: @ShreyaPandita thanks, i had already seen it and followed his tip for debugging. However once you get the error there seems to be no way back but a restart. He even mentions it on his page....

Comment: I guess this is not possible, it can not be recovered from without a kernel restart.

Comment: @Rika would you know or can point me in the direction of "what exactly happens to the GPU when I restart my kernel ?" how is it possible that this cannot be replicated with some code... there must be a way

Comment: You are actually doing something wrong in your code that initiates this. This can be replicated in code in various ways. such as using label -1 or a label larger than your number of classes. Fix your code first. in order to know what goes wrong you can enable `torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True)` and get more information concerning the bit that causes the issue